# Support for localized icons in Android applications

Tags: android, localization, icons

Does Android Market support localized icons for applications? I could not find it on market profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application icon is in a localized drawable-LOCALE folder then on the device, the application icon can be a localized version. Currently with the web market updates, you upload a hi-res application icon when you publish, and that icon is used in the market. So localized icon in the app, standard icon in the market.

Answer (score 4):

You can use qualifiers in mipmap.
For example, I have an app that has two language English and Arabic. I put my English icon app in the normal mipmap and create a new folders for Arabic version. Hope this screenshots clear my point:

**In Finder windows:**
[image]

**In Android Studio:**
[image]

for more info see: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Comment: How to import icon file for different localizations?